# How to Change Change Python 2.7 to Python 3,6 in UBuntu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, pipenv

I need use Python 3.6 in my project, I change my path `./bashrc` with:

`alias python=python3` on the first line.

My problem is, I need use `Pip` and `Pipenv`, and when I try install these packages, they are installed for `python 2.7`, and When I run these commands, they run with `python2.7`.

I need change my Python path to 3.6 and `Pip` and `Pipenv` use with Python 3.6.

What do I do?

Comment: Why not use the virtualenv to manage your environment?

Comment: When I use virtualenv, and use pip, is pip from python 2.7 and not 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Python 3 version of Pip for Ubuntu: `$ apt install python3-pip` and invoke it with `$ pip3`

Comment: Nice, I get it...install `python3-pip` and alter `./bashrc` with `alias pip=pip3`. And remove `python-pip` from `ptyhon2.7`